# app getting crash, while sending data through wifi direct

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I was working sample in this url (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). Two devices are connecting, but app getting crash if i send any data. Please, give some solution or give some others samples regards wifi direct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice lib. `AllJoyn™` which is provide us to data transfer p2p with WIFI. 
https://allseenalliance.org/developers

hope this will help you.

Comment: I don want library. I want to hot code the for the data transmission.Because, this library has more memory than my project.